# Recover data from corrupted SSD

Tags: ssd, data-recovery, ntfs

I have a corrupted external SSD caused by power I think and i want to restore it or at least recover the data. The filesystem now is RAW and used to be NTFS. I already tried EaseUS data recovery but couldn't find all the files. What can I do?

Comment: Contact data recovery professionals. Then start making regular backups.

Comment: Where do I find these professionals?

Comment: Googling will be a good first step :)

Answer (score 0):

Well it's looks like that EaseUS Data recovery had found the files, it's just that I was looking on the Quick Scan Results rather than the Deep Scan Results!